# Java Replace All Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a replaceAll in java that can replace json to be inside of an array instead of a object, Here's an example of what I mean:

```
test:[{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}]
```

my goal is to replace all the of } in test object to be in an array but not effect any other }

(The json that I am using is valid(Unlike the json below) but I've been doing the tests with the string below because i expect it would have the same result and it is much shorter)

```
String test = "[asdfasdf}test:{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}.sdfasdfsadfsdf, test:{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}sdfsdf } ";
```

//Desired Outcome

```
String test = "[asdfasdf}test:[{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}].sdfasdfsadfsdf, test:[{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}]sdfsdf } ";


System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(?<=[test:{])}", "}]")); //
```

So As a side note I would like to point out why I found this question important it is because of a bad supplier that gives back json as an object, rather the an array, if it doesn't have more than one result. Because of this it broke my json class parser

Comment: use proper JSON parsing API.

Comment: Every Json Parsing Api will not work as far as I'm aware, It's because a supplier doesn't return the result in an array even though it generally is an array

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Do you know of any libraries that will implicity convert an object into an array if it inside of one?

Comment: String test = "[asdfasdf}test:[{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}].sdfasdfsadfsdf, test:[{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}]sdfsdf } ";

Comment: If you are interested then let me try. What is the json String?

Comment: String test = "[asdfasdf}test:{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}.sdfasdfsadfsdf, test:{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}sdfsdf } ";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58993/discussion-between-user3218114-and-kevinn2065).

Comment: Do you mean the original? its 2 Gb :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?<=\btest:){[^}]*}
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vM1xR9/2)

Sample code:

```
String input  = "[asdfasdf}test:{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}.sdfasdfsadfsdf, test:{\"asdf\":\"asasdd\"}sdfsdf } ";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?<=\\btest:)\\{[^}]*\\}","[$0]"));
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    \b                       the word boundary
    test:                    'test:'
  )                        end of look-behind
  {                        '{'
  [^}]*                    any character except: '}' (0 or more times)
  }                        '}'
```